# Multiple data insertion with lumen + json

Tags: json, laravel, lumen

i want to insert datas from excel in to my database,
when i read the excel i got the below json format, by using this json how to do my operation.

[{

```
            "name": "jijo",
            "address": "kuzhivelippurath",
            "phone": 9961196748
        },
        {

            "name": "libin",
            "address": "kottayam",
            "phone": 84654564564
        },
        {

            "name": "renju",
            "address": "kottayam",
            "phone": 84654564565
        },
        {

            "name": "revathy",
            "address": "kottayam",
            "phone": 84654564566
        },
        {

            "name": "aiswarya",
            "address": "kottayam",
            "phone": 84654564567
        }]
```

my lumen code is here.

```
DB::table('enquirydetails')->insert(
                    ['name' => data,
                    'address' =>data ,
                    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert all the data with just one DB query, you can prepare the array and use `insert()`:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
DB::table('enquirydetails')->insert($dada);
```

Comment: i want to insert only the name and address.

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A if you don't have `phone` column in your table, you can still use this code. If you have the column, do something like this: `$data = collect(json_decode($json, true))->only(['name', 'address'])->toArray();`

Comment: $data = collect(json_decode($json, true))->only(['name', 'address'])->toArray();    this return only []

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A glad it helped. As an alternative, you could do this `$data . = array_map(function($i) {return  array_only($i, ['name', 'address']); }, json_decode($json, true));`